# How to open a html page from a small plain java created Server?

Tags: java, html, sockets, serversocket

Is there a way to open an HTML page (stored locally) with a small java server app (with ServerSocket/Socket) simply by accessing localhost:port?

To be more specific, when I access localhost from a browser, I want the HTML page to appear.

PS: I want plain Java SE 8. No servlets, JSP or anything else.

I searched and searched on the internet, but i did no quite find anything...

Comment: Sure, just write the file into the socket when you get a connection. The browser will first send a `GET` request, but you can ignore that and just send the file.

Comment: Can you help with some java code. I'm a bit of a n00b. Many Thanks!

Comment: No I can't, you get to learn yourself how to write and read from sockets. Luckily there are a lot of other people who have had the same problem, so with some searching you'll find all the info you need.

Comment: It's not "how" but "what"... Thanks for your answers! I'll try harder to find something using your info.

Comment: You can find plenty of questions about creating servers, writing to sockets, etc. on stackoverflow itself. The SO search can be pretty bad sometimes, but you can google with `site:stackoverflow.com` to get results from SO (since the questions and answers are usually better than on some possibly unreliable sites).